# Filament PHP show custom form or filter row above header widgets and link them with header widgets

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-filament

I am using Filament PHP v3 and have created a custom page. The content of that page presents two header widgets. One line chart and one table widget.

Above those two widgets, I want to display a row with different filter options such as start date, end date, etc.

However, I am having difficulties to archive my goal. I have already tried to use `HasFiltersForm` as well `HasFormSchema` but I am not able to display any forms or filters to input data.

This is my custom page

```
class ShowClicks extends Page
{
    protected static string $resource = ShortUrlClickResource::class;

    protected static string $view = 'filament.resources.short-url-click-resource.pages.show-clicks';

    protected function getHeaderWidgets(): array
    {
        return [
            ShortUrlClicksChart::make(),
            MostShortUrlClicks::make(),
        ];
    }
}
```

When I was using `HasFiltersForm` I have added the following function to my code ([source](https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/panels/dashboard#filtering-widget-data)):

```
ublic function filtersForm(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                Section::make()
                    ->schema([
                        DatePicker::make('startDate'),
                        DatePicker::make('endDate'),
                        // ...
                    ])
                    ->columns(3),
            ]);
    }
```

But there was no filter or form displayed... The same goes for `InteractsWithForms` ([source](https://github.com/filamentphp/filament/discussions/1169#discussioncomment-1930945)):

```
protected function getFormSchema()
    {
        return [
            Forms\Components\TextInput::make('site_name'),
        ];
    }
```

I don't see any form/inputable filter to use on my custom page...

How can I add a row above my header widgets to display filters which interact with my widgets?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

When using the `HasFiltersForm` Trait on a Custom Page you have to add

```
{{ $this->filtersForm }}
```

in your `filament.resources.short-url-click-resource.pages.show-clicks` blade template to display the filters form.

Afterwards pass the filters to the widgets for them to be available in your widget (e.g. `$this->filters['startDate]`).

```php
    protected function getHeaderWidgets(): array
    {
        return [
            ShortUrlClicksChart::make(['filters' => $this->filters]),
            MostShortUrlClicks::make(['filters' => $this->filters]),
        ];
    }
```

Sadly the filter form will be displayed below the widgets.

If you need the filter to be above the widget consider removing the `getHeaderWidgets` function. Instead use the `getFooterWidgets` function or place the widgets directly in to your blade template after the `filtersForm` call.

```
{{ $this->filtersForm }}
@livewire(\App\...\ShortUrlClicksChart::class, ['filters' => $this->filters])
@livewire(\App\...\MostShortUrlClicks::class, ['filters' => $this->filters])
```